# Duration to Seconds in Pandas

Tags: pandas, duration, timedelta, delta

How can i a Series like this:

```
2016-11-09 00:07:00    0 days 00:00:15.000000000
2016-11-09 00:07:15    0 days 00:20:14.000000000
2016-11-09 00:07:30    0 days 10:00:15.000000000
```

into in integer values like this:

```
2016-11-09 00:07:00    15
2016-11-09 00:07:15    1214 // 20*60+14
2016-11-09 00:07:30    36015 // 10*60*60+15
```

Comment: i tried this: auswahl['Delta'] = auswahl['Delta'].dt.total_seconds() but get this: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: That is because your values are likely strings and need to be converted to timedeltas before you can use the `dt` accessor.  You'll see that my answer includes this solution.  `pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are [`TimeDeltas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html).  You should be able to use the [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) method.  However, you'd need to access that method via the `datetime` accessor [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html).  Assuming your series is named `s`

```
s.dt.total_seconds()

2016-11-09 00:07:00       15.0
2016-11-09 00:07:15     1214.0
2016-11-09 00:07:30    36015.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Hower, if by chance those are strings.  It might be better to do use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

```
pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds()

2016-11-09 00:07:00       15.0
2016-11-09 00:07:15     1214.0
2016-11-09 00:07:30    36015.0
dtype: float64
```